# TaskBarButton middle mouse button event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouse, taskbar

I have a TaskBar with buttons. at the TaskBar there is a lot of events, but there is only one event at the click of a button.

```
TaskBar.ButtonClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ToolBarButtonClickEventHandler(this.TaskBarButtonClick);
```

I need an event to a button press TaskBar  middle mouse button.

something like

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
         {
            MessageBox.Show("Middle");
         }
```

only taskbar

I know this example. I did that. the problem is that the event for the Taskbar. I need an event to the button provided on this TaskBar

Comment: What kind of `Control` is your `TaskBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.Button is not of type `MouseButtons`. It is of type `ToolBarButton`. So it references the location on the toolbar that is clicked, not the location on the mouse used to make the click.

**Toolbar Button**

If you need to handle which toolbar button is clicked then reference [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbarbuttonclickeventhandler.aspx) for using the `ToolBarButtonClickEventHandler` works.

```
//add some buttons.
TaskBar.Buttons.Add(new ToolBarButton()); //index 0
TaskBar.Buttons.Add(new ToolBarButton()); //index 1

//add the handler
TaskBar.ButtonClick += new ToolBarButtonClickEventHandler (
    this.taskbar_ButtonClick);

private void taskbar_ButtonClick (Object sender, ToolBarButtonClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Evaluate the Button property to determine which button was clicked. 
    switch(TaskBar.Buttons.IndexOf(e.Button))
    {
        case 0:
            //Whatever you want to do when the 1st toolbar button is clicked
            break; 
        case 1:
            //Whatever you want to do when the 2nd toolbar button is clicked
            break; 
    }
}
```

**Mouse Button**

You could add an event handler for the `MouseDown` event to trap the [Mouse button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mousebuttons.aspx) that was clicked.

```
TaskBar.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.taskbar_MouseDown);

private void taskbar_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Determine which mouse button is clicked. 
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Middle");
    }
}
```

Comment: everything is fine, but I need a middle mouse button click event on the button taskbar.
these two events I know. Event middle mouse button is a button located on the taskbar

Comment: @Pavel, please post the code declaring the Taskbar and all the buttons and the handlers.